# auto refresh ajax div running on php page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, refresh

Please see my code below. I want to auto refresh a `div` on a php page. I tried to refresh through javascript and html header, but it is slowly slowing down my computer.

page2.php

```
<?php

if($_GET['type']!='ajax'){
    include 'header.php';
    echo "<div id='main-content'>";
}
?>
Itm 1</br>
Itm 2

<img class="ajax-loader" src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading..." />

<?php
if($_GET['type']!='ajax'){
    echo "</div>";
    include 'footer.php';
}?>
```

app.js

```
$.cergis = $.cergis || {};
$.cergis.loadContent = function () {
    $('.ajax-loader').show();
     $.ajax({
         url: pageUrl + '?type=ajax',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#main-content').html(data);
            // hide ajax loader
            $('.ajax-loader').hide();

  }
    });
    if (pageUrl != window.location) {
        window.history.pushState({ path: pageUrl }, '', pageUrl);
    }
}
$.cergis.backForwardButtons = function () {
    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: location.pathname + '?type=ajax',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#main-content').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
$("a").on('click', function (e) {
    pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.cergis.loadContent();
    e.preventDefault();
});
$.cergis.backForwardButtons();
```

i have tried different variation but no luck. please help me.

thanks.

app.js changed...

```
function myTimer() {
  $('.ajax-loader').show();
  $.ajax({
      url: pageUrl + '?type=ajax',
      success: function (data) {
          $('#main-content').html(data);
          // hide ajax loader
          $('.ajax-loader').hide();
        }
  });
```

}

```
setInterval(function(){myTimer()}, 1000);
```

Comment: 'showing down'? you sure?

Comment: sorry its slowing down....

Answer (score 1):

Try setTimeout:

```
function myTimer() {
  $('.ajax-loader').show();
  $.ajax({
      url: pageUrl + '?type=ajax',
      success: function (data) {
          $('#main-content').html(data);
          // hide ajax loader
          $('.ajax-loader').hide();
          setTimeout(myTimer,1000);//so that the request ends setTimeout calls a new request.
      },
      error: function () {
          setTimeout(myTimer,1000);//If there is an error in the request the "autoupdate" can continue.
      }
  });
}
myTimer();//fire
```

this way `setTimeout()` waiting to finish the request to invoke a new request.

`setInterval()` does not wait, which makes simuntaneos generate multiple events, which causes the slowness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout($.cergis.loadContent, 1000);` to refresh once or `setInterval($.cergis.loadContent, 1000);` to refresh each seconds (1000 milliseconds = 1second).

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: i tried both of them....actually this time its starts but not end the action...stuck in middle...

Comment: What these functions will do is start the function you give in parameter. So if it doesn't end it's because the function you give is not doing what you call "end the action".

Comment: i changed app.js at the end of original post...basically this ajax changed the div on click....what i want it should change auto...

Comment: $(function(){ setInterval(myTimer, 1000);} will start the interval when DOM is ready